# How to handle the route manipulation by the user

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This question is about a corner case but I still want to deal with it correctly without breaking the user interface or make it look broken.
Minimum should be a 404 page.

Lets assume I have this route:

```
/projects/:projectId/administration/members/:memberId
```

The user now manipulated the route with a memberId that does NOT exist.

The code knows that the memberId does **NOT** exist, because when the database request is done I search for that memberId in the members list.

If the memberId would exist I would highlight that member in that list and another `router.navigate()` method is called to:

```
/projects/:projectId/administration/members/:memberId/tasks
```

But as the memberId does NOT exist and the route is activated already it looks pretty dumb to navigate again to my 404 component...

I do not know in an early stadium - before the route is activated - wether that memberId exists.

So how would you deal with that problem?

Option 1: Navigate very late to 404 page

Option 2: Leave the members list as it is, because you can not highlight that memberId in the route.

Maybe you have more options or a better proposal?

**Happy Path - when the user uses the user interface to navigate**

1. User is on the root path `/projects`
2. User selects a project and click open
3. User gets navigated to child route: `/projects/:projectId/administration/members`
4. A list of members is displayed
5. User selects a member via (click), the member is highlighted and a manual route navigation is done to another child route:   `/projects/:projectId/administration/members/:memberId/tasks`

**Bad Path - when the user manipulates the url to navigate through the ui**

1. User is on the path: `/projects/:projectId/administration/members/:memberId/tasks`
   and manipulates the memberId like 50000 instead of an existing one. No tasks are returned. But... when the user then starts to create a new task for a non-existing memberId and that is saved to the server than it crashes of course as the ForeignKey is invalid...

Creating a **Resolver** for the

route: `/projects/:projectId/administration/members`
is **too early** as there exist no memberId

route: `/projects/:projectId/administration/members/:memberId/tasks`

is **too late** as the tasks is a child route/view of the members list, that would mean my tasks component would have to communicate with the parent members component to sync/check the memberId in the members list. Thats awful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this same reason [Resolve guard is present to Fetch data before navigating.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard).

In below example if crisis is not found user is sent to list.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<Crisis> {
    let id = route.params['id'];
    return this.cs.getCrisis(id).then(crisis => {
      if (crisis) {
        return crisis;
      } else { 

        // id not found 
        this.router.navigate(['/crisis-center']);

        return null;
      }
    });
  }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I have already done a class implements Resolve for switching main menu links/screens. AFAIR I have read somewhere its recommend NOT to use resolve for sub-sub screens. I forgot that link... Also consider I do not have an extra detail/id page. My Members list and the active member is in the same component and on the same route. I have to think about it and maybe rearrange the route a bit, gimme some time...

Comment: When the members and active member(id) is on the same route there is no navigate back to a 'crisis-list' like described in my case which is different from those mvc driven no real world apps :-) Making in the resolver a MemberExistsById call to the server would be nonsense.

Comment: And... the tasks for a member are shown below in a router-outlet on the same page. JFYI. And when no member yet exists because none was created it should still go to the members site ;-)

Comment: Every route is a first class citizen in routing world, ideally there should not be any performance hit if you Resolve in first second or nth level. Real or NO real world example they cover almost all use case, there will be always another use case round the corner which cant be documented. Can you add your happy path use cases as well as in how    navigation happens in your question and why you are unable to find a alternate path in case member Id is not found while updated by user in your corner case.

Comment: You might be having route for `:memberId/tasks` so why not resolve at this path to check if member is present or not, if not redirect to `/projects/:projectId/administration/members` path?

Comment: Catching the memberId via params.subscribe(...) in the tasks-component is too late because I have to communicate back/forth with the parent members component. I will setup tomorrow evening a plunkr that you can play around :-)

Comment: Nope, I am not suggesting to get the params in component via params.subscribe(...), you can add a resolve guard in your route something like `{   path: ':memberId/tasks' , resolve: { member: MemberResolver    }         }`, see the link to the document I have shared, Cheers!!

Comment: resolve guard will ensure that the member is present before navigating to the task route, and there you can decide to navigate to members route instead of task route.

Comment: 2 quick reasons against your suggestion - just doesnt fit my purpose - 1.) I have no access to the members list in this MemberResolver 2.) The members list are chips/tags and when I click on them the tasks are loaded with a spinner over the tasks component. With a resolver I would have to integrate a spinner inside a chip/tag clicking on them which I can`t/won`t do. Resolver is nice for main screen transition but I do not like it within screens.

Comment: 1. Cant you make members list available? 2. Its up to you where and how you want to put your spinner logic. **Resolver is nice for main screen transition but I do not like it within screens** if you do not like it well its up to you how you want to develop your application, we in a community can just suggest, Cheers!!

Comment: Of course I could make another shared memberService inject into the members component and MemberResolver which acts as mediator/observer but why so much effort for something that should work out of the box. I looked today again at named outlets maybe that fits better :-)

Comment: Concerning the core problem, that a non-existing memberId is accepted to resolve data , you are right the resolver is the only solution someone should go. Except some rounter.events.subscribe hacks insinde the members component ;-). About the MembersStore I have to think and wait until the customer finds that bug :P